# C/C++ shared memory, atomic operations, Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, atomic, inter-process-communicat

I'm doing inter-process communication using shared memory on a multi-*processor* server. I've simplified the code to the following:

```
struct MyStruct {
  uint64_t x;
};

volatile MyStruct* my_struct;  // initialized elsewhere

void MyFunction(uint64_t y) {
   while (true) {
      uint64_t current_x = my_struct->x;
      if (__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&my_struct->x, current_x, y)) {
         DoWork(current_x, y);  // do work here depending on current_x and y
         return;
      }
   }
}
```

My question: is this code correct?

In particular, do I need to add a

`__sync_synchronize()`

before the line

`uint64_t current_x = my_struct->x` or will that be redundant since the atomic CAS on the following line effectively does that anyways? As you can see, what effectively I want is the __sync_lock_test_and_set functionality. However, from http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html it looks like that function may not work always as expected.

Comment: Limited knowledge in this area, but I don't believe you need the `__sync_synchronize()`

Comment: Which processor architecture?

Comment: Processor architecture is intel x86_64

Answer (score 0):

```
   while (true) {
      uint64_t current_x = my_struct->x;
      /* CAVEAT: my_struct may point to something different now */
      if (__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&my_struct->x, current_x, y)) {
```

If you don't care that `my_struct` may point to a different structure, but has the same `x` value as the original struct, then the code seems fine. It seems your code implies that it is okay, because your `DoWork` only cares about `current_x` and `y`.